# Is it a good guess that Heaven's joy surpasses even the keenest felt here?

Tags: heaven, nature-of-man

Jonathan Edwards said terms like 'joy' and 'ecstasy' were too meager to describe the greatness of the happiness in Heaven. Was Edwards right in saying our strongest words come nowhere near the reality? Are there levels to happiness (as Thomas of Aquinas thought) or is utter bliss available- but short lived and tainted by sin- here? For instance, romantic love is fairly spectacular- can we guess it is beyond even that? I guess it's the difference between the idea that Heaven as ineffable, versus the idea that Heaven is basically a problem- and sin-free Earth.

Obviously this is all guesswork and we won't truly know until death. Yet can we make an educated guess?

There is some verses in 2 Corinthians 2 that say,

> 9 but just as it is written,
>   “Things which eye has not seen and ear has not heard,
>   And which have not entered the heart of man,
>   All that God has prepared for those who love Him.”
>   10 For to us God revealed them through the Spirit; for the Spirit searches all things, even the depths of God. [(vv.9,10)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20cor%202:9-10&version=NASB).

In light of these verses, the second of which is often not quoted with the first, it seems that God may have revealed some aspects of the things He has prepared for those who love Him. If so, what are some of these things? Are they perhaps mentioned in other scriptures? Am I perhaps misinterpreting 2 Cor 2:9 and 10?

Answer (score 4):

The only person capable of answering your question is someone who has been there, and that person is Jesus. So here is what the Bible says and what Jesus said.

Satan offered Jesus all the Kingdoms of the Earth and all their Glory:

> Again, the devil taketh him up into an exceeding high mountain, and sheweth him all the kingdoms of the world, and the glory of them; And saith unto him, All these things will I give thee, if thou wilt fall down and worship me. Then saith Jesus unto him, Get thee hence, Satan: for it is written, Thou shalt worship the Lord thy God, and him only shalt thou serve (Mat 4:8,9,10 KJV).

So if there were more joy in the Earth than in Heaven why would Jesus "pass" on the devil's offer of all the world's kingdoms and choose instead a cruel, torturous death on a Roman cross?

Here are the things he said concerning the subject:

> - I say unto you, that likewise joy shall be in heaven over one sinner that repenteth, more than over ninety and nine just persons, which need no repentance (Luke 15:7 KJV).
> - Rejoice ye in that day, and leap for joy: for, behold, your reward is great in heaven: for in the like manner did their fathers unto the prophets (Luke 6:23 KJV).

Remember Heaven does not exist for our edification, it is the home of God!

> Thou art worthy, O Lord, to receive glory and honour and power: for thou hast created all things, and for thy pleasure they are and were created (Rev 4:11 KJV).